# How to create a new list by comparing each index value with max of previous values?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is a list abc.In the first loop, I check if preceeding element is greater than the first element(start_equity) or not. If yes, i reassign the current element = start_equity and do the chek from that index of current element. The problem is for second loop. In the second loop, I want to compare value of index to max value of previous elements and if the condition is met score should be appended to scorelist. Please somebody help me with this. I have minimum knowledge in python.

```
abc= [150,110,120,0,0,160,120,-200,140,150]


count= 0
Look = 0
score = 0
scorelist=[]


startequity =  abc[0]
for (index, item) in list(enumerate(abc)):
    if abc[index] < startequity:
        startequity = abc[index]
        Look = Look + 1
        scorelist = scorelist + [0]

    if abc[index] > max(abc[Look:index]):
        count = count + 1
        score = score + count
        scorelist.append((score))
```

Desired answer is scorelist = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1,2, 0,0, 1, 2]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  I'm fixing your indentation error; you also have undefined symbols.

Comment: @Prune mentioned MCVE for a reason.  What is `Equity_list` or `Look`? Your description of the procedure is also not really clear to explain, what you try to achieve with your procedure.

Comment: @Prune I just edited the undefined symbol. Thank you for editing the indent. I tried to explain the problem as much as possible in the statement above the code. Please help me with this.

Comment: @Piinthesky I just edited the undefined "Equity_list". Thank you

Comment: @Prune I edited the description as well. Please let me know what is unclear and I will explain again. Please help me with this. Thank you

Comment: Again, we should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Fix the execution crash.

Comment: @Piinthesky can you please help me with this? I really need help. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Well done for your starting attempts and being brave enough to ask for help. Let's see here...

Look hasn't been defined.

max(); must have at least one element or it raises an exception, crashing Python. Having a line like this would work:

```
if index == 0:
    scorelist = scorelist + [0]
    continue
```

I have put a "continue" in that block. Continue tells Python to forget about everything else in the loop and just move on the next cycle in the for loop.

Of note, the following 3 lines all add an element to the end of the list, but it is good convention to use the same notation throughout your code:

```
scorelist = scorelist + [0]
scorelist.append(0)
scorelist += [0]
```

Final code (Edited Version):

```
abc= [150,110,120,0,0,160,120,-200,140,150]

score = 0
scorelist=[]

for (index, item) in list(enumerate(abc)):
    if index == 0:
        scorelist.append(0)
        continue

    if abc[index] < abc[index-1]:
        scorelist.append(0)
        score = 0

    else:
        score = score + 1
        scorelist.append((score))

print(scorelist)
```

This returns [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2] as asked in the question.

Comment: JimmyCarlos Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I assigned Look = 0. Sorry, I had forgotten this one. In your answer, in the last if I want to compare abc[index] >= max(abc[Look:inde]). Look with be increased everytime startequity is reassigned.

Comment: Try running the code in the last grey box in my answer. :-)

Comment: JimmyCarlos I ran your code, this is mostly what I am looking for. Except the scorelist is missing one 0 at the fourth place from end. The list len should be 10. Also, for the third if statement if abc[index] >=max(startequity:abc[index-1]). would you please take a look one more time? Thank you

Comment: There you go, fixed! Have a nice day.

Comment: JimmyCarlos: Thank you so very much. I really appreciate your time explaining and helping me with the code. This makes me more interested to learn. Thank you again. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

I am still not 100% clear, what you try to do. But I guess the output is supposed to be the following: If the previous element in `abc` is larger or non-existent, then assign zero, otherwise increase the number by one.

This is at least, what this code does:

```
abc= [150,110,120,0,0,160,120,-200,140,150]

res = [0]
for i in [[1, 0][u - v < 0] for u, v in zip(abc[1:], abc[:-1])]:
    if i == 0:
        count = 0
    else:
        count += 1
    res.append(count)

print(res)
```

Explanation: 
`[[1, 0][u - v < 0] for u, v in zip(abc[1:], abc[:-1])]` is a list comprehension that assigns `0` or `1` depending on the comparison with the previous element. This excludes the first element, for which the score is set to `0`.
The `for loop` then ignores `0` and substitutes a series like `1,1,1...` with `1,2,3...`

Comment: Piinthesky, Thank you for the explanation and your code. I really appreciate it. JimmyCarlos answer is very close to what I am looking for. Thank you again